# generate vs studio can not open boost library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost, cmake

I have a cmake file that adds boost to a project.

the section that I add boost to project is as follow:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(BOOST_ROOT $ENV{BOOST_ROOT})
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR ${BOOST_ROOT}/lib64-msvc-12.0)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS thread system unit_test_framework filesystem REQUIRED)
```

and I add boost to my project in this way:

target_link_libraries(MyProject
     ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY})

When I compile my code, I am getting this error:

```
cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_57.lib'
```

looking at project file, I can see that this library was added to project in correct way (input section of linker):

```
C:\Local\boost\lib64-msvc-12.0\boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_57.lib
```

I have a similar setup on another computer which works perfectly. The difference between the two computer is:

working computer: windows 7 +VS 2012

not working computer Windows 8.1 + Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: `libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_57.lib` != `boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_57.lib`

Comment: @Axalo Thanks. I did no noted that, I need to work on my "Attention to detail", By what it is different? Why I is using a different library?

Comment: Also `lib64-msvc-12.0` == Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: @drescherjm Why not? what is correct?

Comment: I think you are talking about VS2013 (the non working setup) in this question anyways (even though the tag says `visual-studio-2012`).

Comment: There is a way to control the naming convention when you build boost. Also I believe cmake has some control. Although in both cases I use the defaults when I build boost and have cmake use it with Visual Studio versions.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks. Can you please elaborate? How can I change cmake to fix this problem?

Comment: @axalo Thanks, based on your observation, I fixed the problem. Can you put it into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_57.lib` is obviously not the same as
`boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_57.lib` you will have to either change the name in the generated project's properties or in cmake itself.

Comment: Based on this answer, I found what was the problem: If you look at find_packge command, you would see that I found several boost packages, but when I add them to project as library, I only added filesystem. Since I had some libraries that uses boost::system library, the linker could not find system library and hence the error. There are two ways to fix it: 1- Add all pcakages by adding ${BOOST_LIBRARIES} instead of ${BOOS_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY} 2- add library search path to projects.